# lightning url hack for lookup field

Tags: configuration, urlhacking, quickaction

I'm trying to prepopulate the lookup field in child objects from the related list of parent.

But it seems the URL hack is not working for that.
Event when I hardcode the value, it's still not working

```
/lightning/o/CustomObjectA/new?recordTypeId=0126g000000Ogh8&
defaultFieldValues=
00N6g00000UQ7Fa_lkid={!CustomObjectB.AccountId__c}
```

Comment: Have you tried using the API name of the field instead of  `00N6g00000UQ7Fa_lkid`

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue. On several tries this worked

/lightning/o/Product2/new?recordTypeId=....&defaultFieldValues=ParentProduct__c={!Product2.Id}